# Why are there 2 commas when writing X, Y, and Z in a paragraph/sentence but only 1 when writing that in a title?

Tags: oxford-comma

For example, "John liked bacon, eggs, and sausages" is correct but if I see an album or song title with that same pattern like "Money, Women & Cars" is correct.

First, are the commas correct in both iterations and if so, why is it so?

Comment: mandatory reading: http://www.grammarly.com/blog/2015/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

Comment: There are differing viewpoints as to when a comma is "required" after "and" in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extra comma is called an [Oxford Comma](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/what-is-the-oxford-comma), and it is optional in American English.  There is no specific rule about titles and other text; use is left to the personal choice of the author.